# Anyone heard of 'tank tracking'?

Tags: seo, googlebot, blackhat, honeypots

Someone I know told me about some seriously cutting edge blackhat SEO that he called 'tank tracking'.  He said that it is some sort of code (he believes written in Python) that 'sits' around the outside perimeter of your visible webpage and listens for an incoming search spider.  when a spider enters the page, it traps it in this weird wormhole, making it loop through, I don't know, certain keywords or something.... the result is that a SE like google would consequently give the page a full 100 rating (this person told me Google bestows some sort of scoring app once you've passed a certain number of their exams).  A quick google search on 'tank tracking seo', 'tank tracking blackhat seo' and 'tank tracking google' yielded zero results.
Let me backtrack a bit and say that I am not interested in utilizing blackhat techniques.  I'm just astonished that something like this might be out in the world.  Anyone heard of this?

**UPDATE**  I have tried googling "seo honeypot" and "search engine honeypot" and "search engine wormhole" and I cannot find anything anywhere about this.  Either the hackers who are doing this stuff aren't commenting about it at all online or it just doesn't exist in the way I was told it exists.  I appreciate your helpful answers.

Comment: Having written scripts which poison spiders (for some obnoxious spiders which ignored my robots.txt) I can assure you that, if a script of this nature exists, it will quickly be recognized by whomever operates the spider and its output will be ignored.

Comment: @danlefree, why bother writing a script? Couldn't you just block the spider (i.e. add their IP addresses in your firewall)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not heard of it but it sounds similar to the [doorway pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorway_page) that [BMW were blacklisted for using](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/4685750.stm) back in 2006.

Comment: No, this is different.  The spider isn't redirected off the page.  It stays trapped in this, like, loop, of content on the page or something.  It's weird.  It is supposedly similar to an older trap called a wormhole, some invisible element on the page that traps a spider until the wormhole code releases it (this is all new to me, I never thought about a webpage trapping a spider before).

Comment: @HeatherWalters there is an old spam poisoning technique that involves trapping a spider in an endless series of links, it does sound a little unlikely though.

Comment: The more things change, the more they stay the same. An infinite content honeytrap probably will be recognized pretty quickly by Google and given a dose of digital Malthion.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to trap Google bot, they crawl specific links and if a script is generating false links where there is no content they'll stop crawling you and possibly manually review why Google bot got stuck.

Google is very capable of avoiding calendars on forums which turn into endless loops of links with dates going on forever. So if they can recognize those any script which is somehow generating links without content isn't going to help you once a Googler investigates why Google bot got hung up abnormally on your domain. Then you're PR drops and your rankings. Look what happened to BMW in Germany.